# CORS problem when sending Bearer token from angular

Tags: angular, spring-boot, cors, authorization, angular9

The problem is that authorization header is not sent when sending GET request to localhost.
Preflight request ( OPTIONS ) doesn't contain authorization header and returns 401 status.
I am using Angular interceptor to add header to my request and Spring Boot as backend server.
This is console in Developer Firefox when sending GET request.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/86FpG.png)

Comment: did you setup CORS on server?

Comment: You, need to enable cors origin in your backend service as well.
I guess you have missed that part while constructing apis. Please refer the following doc to follow the instructions on how to enable the cors origin for some particular endpoint. https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/

Comment: On my rest controller i added @CrossOrigin("*") and also added header in response in backend filter. So I did handled that well.
BTW thanks for answering that fast.

Comment: Are you using auth0 for fetching the token? You can also see your request in inspect in the network section. and can verify what you are missing.

Comment: Yes, I did. I added annotation on controller which enables all origin and also in header I added Access-Control-Allow-Origin in response.

Comment: I am not using auth0. Weird thing is that it worked before.
In network I don't have token in preflight request but it returns 401, but original request actually contains authorization token. What else can help you try to understand my problem?

Comment: You must have your security config file in spring boot, if not please add that, and allow all api with method option.

Comment: I do have configuration file. Aren't all methods allowed by default?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your CORS filter :

```
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.core.Ordered;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration;
import org.springframework.web.cors.UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource;
import org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;    

@Component
public class CorsFilterConfig {

    public static final List<String> allowedOrigins = Arrays.asList("*");

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean<CorsFilter> initCorsFilter() {
        // @formatter:off
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
        config.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Authorization", "Cache-Control", "Content-Type"));
        config.addAllowedMethod("*");
        config.setAllowedOrigins(allowedOrigins);
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        FilterRegistrationBean<CorsFilter> bean = new FilterRegistrationBean<>(new CorsFilter(source));
        bean.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
        return bean;
        // @formatter:on
    }
}
```

Interceptor at Angular:

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
  HttpRequest,
  HttpHandler,
  HttpEvent,
  HttpInterceptor,

  HttpResponse
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { AppService } from '../services/app.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import { tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { ProgressBarService } from '../services/progress-bar.service';

@Injectable()
export class HttpTokenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private app: AppService, private router: Router,
              private progressService: ProgressBarService) {
  }

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const url = environment.api_url;
    if (req.url.indexOf('/oauth/') === -1) {  
      const token = this.app.getToken();
      const contentType = req.url.indexOf('/fileupload') >= 0  ? 'multipart/form-data' : 'application/json; charset=utf-8';
      let changeReg = req.clone({
        url: url + req.url,
        headers: req.headers
          .set('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8')
          .set('Accept', 'application/json; charset=utf-8')
          .set('Authorization', token)
      });
      if (req.url.indexOf('/upload') >= 0 || req.url.indexOf('/fileupload') >= 0) {
        changeReg = req.clone({
          url: url + req.url,
          headers: req.headers
            .set('Authorization', token)
        });
      }
      this.progressService.show();
      return next.handle(changeReg).pipe(
        tap((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
          if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
            this.progressService.hide();
          }
        }, (error) => {
          this.progressService.hide();
        })
      );
    } else {
      this.progressService.show();
      const changeReg = req.clone({ url: url + req.url});
      return next.handle(changeReg).pipe(
        tap((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
          if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
            this.progressService.hide();
          }
        }, (error) => {
          this.progressService.hide();
        })
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Just remove whatever seems extra for you, good luck.

Comment: Do I have to inject cors config component somewhere?

Comment: My angular interceptor is fine. I added cors config as component in spring boot and it worked. I'm not sure why but thanks anyway.

Comment: no need to inject cors configs to angular side, if its on production env make sure both are on https or http

Comment: Thanks. I spent a lot of time searching and I even tried some cors filter I found but it didn't work. Obviously HIGHEST_PRECENDENCE is the key.